# Bootstrap nav dropdown not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get the bootstrap dropdown to work or the button when the menu collapses in tablet/mobile view. Here is my html for nav:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="brand" height="50" width="100" src="media/expend-logo.svg"></a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>
```

These are the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
     });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Bootstrap did you add to the page?

Comment: 3.3.7 - the one posted on their website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't included scripts properly. This is what worked for me.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="brand" height="50" width="100" src="media/expend-logo.svg"></a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. hope it works.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fix-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                <img src="imgs/your image here" width="300" height="300" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div id="nav-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="page one">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="another page">
                        About
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="third link">
                        Contact us
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <div id="nav-options" class="btn-group pull-right hidden-xs">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle thumbnail" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            Academics
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="link1"><p class="text-center"> Link page</p></a> </li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="link2"><p class="text-center"> Linkpage 2</p></a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="link3"><p class="text-center"> Link page 3</p></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and remember this